# Calculate volume of solid obtained by rotating region bounded by $y=x^2$, line $y= −2$, from $x=0$ to $x=2$ around line $y=−2$.

Tags: calculus, volume, solid-geometry, solid-of-revolution

**Problem :** Calculate the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the function $y=x^2$, the line $y= −2$, from $x=0$ to $x=2$ around the line $y=−2$.

**My Attempt**
[image]

Can someone guide more clearly? Thanks

Comment: Instead of doing it as one whole integral. Try doing it as two seperate integrals. Cylinder with h=2 (from y=-2 to y=0) and radius r=2 (from x=0 to x=2). And above integral i.e. region under parabola

Comment: which mean one by one after that sum? also the rotating respective to x or y?

Comment: Sorry, sorry i thought it as rotation around y-axis forget what i said. I'll delete it.

Comment: oh okay  thanks for trying to help, does that mean this question the rotation around x-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a slice parallel to the $y-$axis of thickness $dx$. Think of it as a cylindrical disk, with height (thickness) $dx$, centered on line $y=-2$. Then the radius of this disk is $y+2$. Thus the volume of this disk is $\pi(y+2)^2\, dx$. Now we stack all such slices to compute the total volume. So
$$\text{Volume} = \int_{\color{red}{x=0}}^{\color{red}{x=2}} \pi (y+2)^2 \, d\color{red}{x} =\pi\int_0^2(x^2+2)^2 \, dx.$$
Hopefully you can complete it now.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer, I apriciate that :D I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Now, Let's think it like this. If we are bounded above by x-axis instead of $y=x^2$ then we would have a perfect cylinder with radius=2, height=2 integral of this cylinder can be written as

$$\pi \int_0^2 (y^2)dx $$ where y is constant which is 2.

Now returning to your question we can see that y is not constant it depends on x. and y can be writtten as $y=2+x^2$ so putting this into above integral gives us

$$ \pi \int_0^2 (2+x^2)^2dx$$ you can handle the rest.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! i will try it

Comment: I post this because of my failure above but as i was writing i didn't see new answer has been post so please accept @AnuragA 's answer as accepted one.

Comment: okay will do :D